# Numeric and String Operations in Golang

Tags: go

https://go.dev/doc/effective_go

```
func nextInt(b []byte, i int) (int, int) {
    for ; i < len(b) && !isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
    }
    x := 0
    for ; i < len(b) && isDigit(b[i]); i++ {
        x = x*10 + int(b[i]) - '0'
    }
    return x, i
}
```

I don't know what kind of operation the following part of the above code is.

```
int(b[i]) - '0'
```

It's a subtraction of a number and a string, but what kind of calculation is it?
Where can I find it in the official documentation or something similar?

Comment: It's a subtraction of a number of type `int` and a *`rune`* - a literal in single quotes has the type `rune` in Go. It is the unicode codepoint value of the digit zero: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0030

Comment: The single quotes in Go are **not** quotes for strings. The language spec ("official documentation") is available under https://go.dev/ref/spec .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a single-quoted literal in Go is `rune`.
`rune` is an alias for `int32`, but more importantly, it represents the Unicode codepoint value for a character.

You can read some background in this blog post on "[Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings)"

The `b []byte` (slice of bytes) is interpreted by the `nextInt` function as a the UTF-8 representation of a series of Unicode characters. Luckily, for ASCII numeric digits, you only need 8 bits (a `byte`) to represent the character, not a full `rune`.

The ASCII value, which is a subset of the Unicode codepoint set, of the digits 0 to 9 are following each directly. So if you take the ASCII value of a digit, and you subtract the ASCII value of the digit zero from it, you end up with the numeric value of the digit.

That's what is happening here.

A minor detail is that in Go, normally you can only subtract values of exactly the same type from each other. And in this case, you wouldn't be able to subtract a `rune` from an `int`. But constants in Go are untyped. They only have a default type (`'0'` has default type `rune`) but are automatically coerced to comply with the context, so `'0'` ends up having the effective type `int`.